# How to get the middle value off a website (Web Scraping)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, cheerio

There are three classes called gauge-value I want to get the second one but it is not outputting anything. I am doing web scraping on on this site https://stockx.com/supreme-hot-wheels-fleet-flyer-1992-bmw-m3-red here is the area that I'm trying to get the middle value out of http://prntscr.com/nfk6x8 I thought that let porText = porHeading.first().next().text(); would work but it did not.

I have already tried to get the first one and last one (Both Work)
let porText = porHeading.first().text(); 
let porText = porHeading.last().text();

```
        ///Check the site like to find gauge-value
        const porHeading = $(".gauge-value");
        let porText = porHeading.first().next().text();

        ///Trying to log number
        console.log(porText);

        ///Removing percent
        porText = porText.replace("%","");

        ///Final Value
        console.log('-----');
        console.log(porText);
        console.log('-----');
```

I want to get the number without the percent of the middle gauge-value text (Should be around 213.3%) when I run the program it is blank but when i do .first() or .last() it works fine. 
-Thanks for the help, Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) jQuery function as well.

```
let porText = porHeading.eq(1).text();
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks this worked great I'm kind of confused what .eq() does, I looked it up could you maybe briefly explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Think of all the $(".gauge-value") elements as an array with index 0. When you do .eq(1), it is basically as good as saying objElements[1] so it takes the 2nd element matching the selector.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, But thanks this will help a lot in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector:

```
document.querySelector("div.gauges > div:nth-child(2) > div.gauge-value").textContent; //213.3%
```